# gauges fluctuating but vehicle won't turn over

Tags: starting

Ok, drove vehicle all over with no problems.  Tonight I go to move it and nothing.  Brake petal is firm, can't shift it.  Won't start but singers and lights work..speedometer and rpm guages are going up and down but nothing else is happening.  It is a 2003 trailblazer.

Please help!! :(

Comment: All my fuses are good.  Battery is good.  Don't click or nothing when trying to turn it over but rpm says 2.5 and speed is 70-90 mph yet not going nowhere...lol

Comment: Does this have an alarm system, if so, factory or aftermarket brand? Can you take off both battery cables?  If so, take both off and make sure contacts are shiny and put them back on for starters.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Sorry to say, but this question is just too broad to be able to know what is wrong. It literally could be so many things. Any more detail you could add would be helpful.